# SED replacement in a set of files in Linux

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I have a following requirement

String 1 : http://gaa-dev.gk.gbcd:9701/analytics

String 2 : https://gaa-prod.gk.gbvd/analytics

There were around 40 different locations in various files(xml content) under /home/gaauser

I want String1 to be REPLACED BY String2

Tried SED, but no luck and I am struck now. Any inputs greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: How exactly did you "try sed"?

Comment: Try using a different delimiter in sed - `sed 's#http://...#https://...#g'` instead of `sed 's/http:\/\/...`

Comment: sed "s/<string1>/<string2>/g" .

Comment: Kevin , didnt get you quite right.. is that something like sed 's#http://gaa-dev.gk.gbcd:9701/analytics/#https://gaa-prod.gk.gbvd/analytics #g'

Comment: @user3621031 Yes you can use almost any character as delimiter in sed. `sed -i 's*http://lalala*http://lololo*g'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two fixes are needed:

- Since you have `/` in your strings, it is recommended to use a different delimiter or you need to tell sed that it is not a delimiter by escaping them.
- Since you are using variables, use double quotes to allow them to interpolate.

```
str1='http://gaa-dev.gk.gbcd:9701/analytics'
str2='https://gaa-prod.gk.gbvd/analytics'
```

```
echo 'http://gaa-dev.gk.gbcd:9701/analytics' | sed "s/$str1/$str2/"
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

```
echo 'http://gaa-dev.gk.gbcd:9701/analytics' | sed "s|$str1|$str2|"
https://gaa-prod.gk.gbvd/analytics
```

Comment: wouldn't hold my breadth for the OP finding the check button, in the meantime, a +1 for effort and patience!